# Flutter WebView: If no internet show different content

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I have a flutter web view app. I would like to have an offline screen with text and the button "try again".

If there is no internet connection (in real-time, no need to refresh and click to check connection), once he lost connection, show the screen with text and try again button. Then if the connection is successfully get the user back to the page where he was.

My current main.dart:

```
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    const MaterialApp(
      home: WebViewApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class WebViewApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const WebViewApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<WebViewApp> createState() => _WebViewAppState();
}

class _WebViewAppState extends State<WebViewApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        elevation: 0,
        toolbarHeight: 0,
      ),
      body: const WebView(
        javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
        initialUrl: 'https://google.com',
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) package, relying on [onWebResourceError](https://pub.dev/documentation/webview_flutter/latest/webview_flutter/WebResourceError-class.html) you could do something like:

```dart
controller = WebViewController()
      ..setNavigationDelegate(
        NavigationDelegate(
          onWebResourceError: (error) {
            if (error.errorType == WebResourceErrorType.hostLookup) {
              setState(() {
                internetDisconnected = true;
              });
            }
          },
        ),
      )
      ..loadRequest(Uri.parse(state.url));
```

and then conditionally show your "no internet" content:

```dart
 !internetDisconnected
                    ? WebViewWidget(
                        controller: controller,
                      )
                    : Center(
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            SvgPicture.asset(
                              "no_signal.svg",
                              width: MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).width / 2,
                            ),
                            const SizedBox(height: 20),
                            Text(
                              "no network",
                              style: largerText,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      )
```

> For more info: [WebResourceErrorType.hostLookup](https://pub.dev/documentation/webview_flutter_platform_interface/latest/webview_flutter_platform_interface/WebResourceErrorType.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a package like internet connection checker. Example [this](https://pub.dev/packages/internet_connection_checker)
One. And check for internet status like

```
bool result = await InternetConnectionChecker().hasConnection;
if(result == true) {
 return Webview();
} else {
 print('No internet :( Reason:');
 return Center(
  child: Text(" no internet"),
 );
}
```

Comment: How can I implement that into main.dart?
My code above..

Comment: In place or return scaffold check the internet and return the other widget